# Using Earpods on PC with TRRS to 2xTRS splitter

Tags: audio, microphone, ear-phones

I just purchased a 4-pin to 2x3-pin audio adapter to use my earpods on a PC. However when I test the microphone all I can hear is a high pitched noise. The earpods are confirmed working on a retina MBP and android phone (everything works on MBP, mic + centre button works on android phone but no volume control as expected). I have tested a pair of beats in-ear earphones with the new splitter, and they're working perfectly (audio + mic). The beats earphones also work with my MBP. Any ideas on why the earpods don't like my splitter? I'm fairly certain beats and apple use the same CTIA standard.

Comment: by the way, the distribution of the TRRS in the earbuds is different from others earphones, the pods are Left Audio, Right Audio, Ground, Mic and the regular ones(not mac) are Left Audio, Right Audio, Mic, Ground

Comment: Can anyone confirm what @user131416 says? The earbud+mic combos on Amazon usually both Apple + Android device compatible so I doubt they'd use different standard.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your audio drivers and restart. Just use the Microsoft default driver.
If it still not working, just press the middle button once.

It seems like the problem comes with these buttons, not the mic.